# Is there any reason to disable paste password on login?

Tags: passwords, web-application, password-management

Today I logged in to pay my cellphone bill, and I found that the site has disabled paste functionality in password field.

I'm a webdev and I know how to *fix* this, but for regular user is **REALLY** annoying having to type a random password like `o\&$t~0WE'kL`.

I know that is normal to make users write the password when *creating an account*, but is there any reason to disable pasting passwords *during login*?

Comment: I've heard the theory that "we want to train users to keep their password off the vulnerable clipboard" ... but if that's been compromised, is the keyboard any safer?

Comment: why do you think it's "normal to make users write the password when creating an account"? that's exactly the same: it hinders the use of Password Managers (which for example generate good new passwords to use when creating an account)

Comment: Note that blocking scripts can sometimes help, but they may be served from the same server as scripts you actually want, making a simple noscript solution a bit less easy. Pasting, logging in, then hitting "temporarily allow..." could help you.

Comment: one thing I've noticed in some sites, Microsoft's login for instance, is that they have disable the "paste" in the contextual menu, but you can `CTRL/CMD + v` to paste the password.

Comment: @DaniEll I would think that they disable password pasting when creating an account so people don't write the wrong password in the first field, and copy the wrong password to the second field...

Comment: not to mention, since it does not prevent the user from *copying* their password from wherever, it does not make the clipboard any safer. By the time the user realize paste does not work, it is too late.

Comment: No not at call. Sounds like a Financial Institution's _Security Expert_'s idea. Like *hey, let's limit the length to 15, for [insert-bad-reason]*.

Comment: @Dupontrocks11 you normally can't copy text *out of* a password field in any system, so you couldn't copy the wrong password from the first field to the second. The closest you could come is pasting the wrong password into both fields from somewhere else.

Comment: I find it extremely annoying when I cannot paste in a password, so if your company wants to annoy people, or risk having users change their passwords to something simple to type (and easier to hack/guess)

Comment: What about click-and-drag method? I find that works when fonts don't paste.
It is not helpful for autopasting, but it is good for certain situations, like when you cannot preview what's typed. It eliminates that small irritant: "Did I type that in right?" If a whole jumble of passwords are pasted togetherlikethisandinotorder, then can't one just highlight and click-and-drag to "paste?" Pardon me, if I am mistaken. --BLBU

Comment: Great idea. Disable all pastes even. You should flood the entire clipboard and also disable the hardware keyboard. Also disable the monitor and enforce password schema that changes/resets every session end, requiring 5 regional hindi symbols in a row 10 times at 256 chars length, where you cant repeat a password you used previously. If someone hasn't logged in during the span of 2 days, reset it anyways. And change their username. Then to really make it safe, enable 2 factor auth where the second factor is a certified [snailmail] letter to the address found on your social security info ;)

Comment: @dhaupin: Did you design the login form for my bank?

Comment: @MarkKCowan lol I do wish someday I could work for a bank. Pull em out of the early 90's and introduce them to the basic concepts of early 2000's "Web2.0" at $180k/yr. Need post-2011 concepts? Yikes, thats scary/bleeding-edge stuff there. So take it easy ya'll elderly CTO + board -- remember your heart issues, don't get too excited. Slow and low...don't worry about those MD5 algos, but keep the password madness because we all agree that greybeards know best.

Comment: @plainclothes: "I've heard the theory that "we want to train users to keep their password off the vulnerable clipboard" ... but if that's been compromised, is the keyboard any safer?" While that might be true, the main point might be one of preventing an easily avoidable trace of forensic evidence by keeping it off the clipboard?

Comment: Can you ask and answer a question about how to get around this. And then link it here. I would up-vote both the question and answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do some sites block pasting into username or password input fields?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2411/why-do-some-sites-block-pasting-into-username-or-password-input-fields)

Comment: note for reviewers for question closure: I personally decided to vote leaving this question opened as it contains answers which are higher quality than the duplicate suggested by IBam; the suggested question appears to only contain opinion based answers

Comment: A user does not know that you disabled the paste functionality until he fails to paste his password. So the password is already in the clipboard. Yo do not improve security, you just annoy your users.

Answer (score 272, accepted):

There is no substantial security benefit to disallowing pasted passwords; on the contrary it is likely to *weaken* security by discouraging the use of password managers to generate and autofill randomized passwords. While some password managers are capable of overriding pasting restrictions, the point still stands that users should not be forced to type their password by hand.

Excerpt from a relevant [WIRED article](https://www.wired.com/2015/07/websites-please-stop-blocking-password-managers-2015/):

> **Websites, Please Stop Blocking Password Managers. It’s 2015**
>
> But what’s crazy is that, in 2015, some websites are intentionally
>   disabling a feature that would allow you to use stronger passwords
>   more easily—and many are doing so because they wrongly argue it makes
>   you safer.
>
> Here’s the problem: Some sites won’t let you paste passwords into
>   login screens, forcing you, instead, to type the passwords out. This
>   makes it impossible to use certain kinds of password managers that are
>   one of the best lines of defense for keeping accounts locked down.

Comment: Another article that covers "defences" of this practice: https://www.troyhunt.com/the-cobra-effect-that-is-disabling/

Comment: Sounds like some good ol' *Name & Shame* is in order. Who the heck intentionally does that?

Comment: @AndrewHoffman PayPal was doing it for a while.  Not sure if they've come to their senses.

Comment: Fidelity and eClinicalWeb are two sites I use regularly (not by choice) that make life really difficult for password managers, seemingly on purpose. They don't block pasting, but they do go out of their way to make password managers fail in bizarre ways.

Comment: Could be worse. The .gov site for  buying T-bills required the on-screen keyboard with random letter placement to mouse-type. Utter torture for a random strong password, and after doing that once I fixed it with greasemonkey.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede PayPal seems to have reversed the problem, at least for me. If I try to autofill with LastPass, it tells me my password is wrong, but if I have LastPass copy my password to my clipboard and I paste it manually, it works just fine.

Comment: I can't stand when I can't "paste" my password. As an avid password manager user I have a password for just those sites. It's not secure and it's not strong. Essentially, i might as well just use the word password. I also consider that entire site to be insecure because of that.

Comment: If you use chrome, enjoy [don't f*** with paste](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dont-fuck-with-paste/nkgllhigpcljnhoakjkgaieabnkmgdkb?hl=en), because seriously websites, don't f*** with paste.

Comment: Just saying, but "it's [current year]" is not an argument

Answer (score 110):

Disabling pasting a password field introduces a "[Cobra effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobra_effect)". A Cobra effect "occurs when an attempted solution to a problem actually makes the problem worse."

[Troy Hunt recently wrote an article where he explains it in more detail](https://www.troyhunt.com/the-cobra-effect-that-is-disabling/). It's essentially a security theater, like what happens at airports to "make us safer". Troy Hunt calls it a Cobra effect because it disables the use of secure, 50-character passwords that would be pasted from a password manager. At best, it forces people to create passwords that are easy to remember and thus more hackable.

Some might say that it makes you safer because it prevents your clipboard from being copied by malware, but they ignore the fact that if malware can already do that, they can also copy all kinds of keypresses, not just Ctrl+V. It's pointless.

From a UX perspective, it's just annoying, like you say. So it's annoying from a UX perspective, and it doesn't make us safer. There's no point to this "feature".

Comment: While I agree with your answer in general I disagree with your opinion on clipboard safety. Flash player for instance is able to access the clipboard but I think it cannot log your key presses (at least as long as the flash object is not focused)

Comment: If [Adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS2F6A31B9-1AE6-4b23-9C12-57A33F4F0516.html) is correct, Flash player can only read the clipboard when the user actively pastes something from it.

Comment: Honestly, if your excuse for not being able to paste passwords on your website is "we are concerned about malicious flash plugins stealing your credentials", then I really wonder why you allow malicious flash plugins on your website in the first place. there are 2 ways any website could have this happen: through malvertising and through site compromise, and those usually do much worse stuff than steal one (usually unique) credential for one site.

Comment: I agree with the spirit of this answer, but it's wrong to say that it is 100% pointless. There *are* scenarios where clipboard compromise can occur, but keylogging (or other attacks) either can't or are less likely. Example: a locked down kiosk OS, or an opportunistic attacker who happens to witness a password paste.

Answer (score 37):

No, there is no sensible reason for doing this. It is bad UX, plain and simple. Disabling pasting into a password field is actually encouraging bad passwords. Password managers automatically clear out the clipboard after pasting, so that argument is no longer valid.

Comment: Some password managers* I use LastPass which is a pretty big name password manager and it does not clear my clipboard

Comment: @DasBeasto it does, but not after pasting, but after a specific set time of copying it. It will also clear the clipboard on exiting the application

Comment: Even if it where true that password managers clear out clipboards after pasting not everyone uses password managers, and people will copy-paste from other sources as well.

Comment: What about detecting the paste in the javascript in the login form and clear the clipboard afterwards? Is javascript powerful enough?

Comment: @beppe9000 Why screw with the user's clipboard at all. They are the user, presumably they know what they are doing and are the best positioned to manage their own passwords. Perhaps they have a system that does something more intelligent than what the web page does. What if they just want to see what their password manager pasted to troubleshoot a technical issue?

Comment: @Sqeaky I mean that if they absolutely want to mess with user's clipboard they should be doing it *after* a paste.

Answer (score 27):

The main security argument to disallow copy&pasting of passwords is that the password remains in the users clipboard afterwards. This can lead to accidental exposure of the password in an unrelated context. For example when the user then accidently pastes it into a different input field in a different application (web or otherwise). Another possible scenario could be when the user walks away from their device without locking it and someone else presses ctrl+v to check what they have in their clipboard.

However, this is a really small risk compared to the huge security advantages password managers have. Also, password managers often have a feature to auto-clear the clipboard a few seconds after copying a password from them which greatly reduces this risk.

Comment: There's also one big problem with this logic, which is that you would already have copied your password before you found out you couldn't paste it...

Comment: @AntP But you will only make that "mistake" the first time you try to log into the website with your password manager, not every single time you use the application.

Comment: True enough... Mostly because I wouldn't be logging in a second time :)

Comment: Yeah, I think the really misguided motive here is assuming that this practice will "train" users to never copy their password into the clipboard, when all it will really do is force them to work around it on this particular site.

Comment: It's merely shifting vulnerability from clipboard-logger to keylogger. Which itself is a red flag that devs doesn't know much about security and the site should be avoided : )

Comment: @Philipp Only if you log in frequently enough that you remember it doesn't work. If you only log in once a month or three times a year, you're likely to forget and try again, or maybe even try again hoping they got rid of the "feature."

Comment: a good password manager will clear clipboard after certain time, mine is configured to do that after 15 secs

Answer (score 13):

There are reasons to do it, though not very good ones.

Basically, it discourages copy and pasting. This means users are less likely to forget it on their clipboard and have it accidentally leaked. Also if they are pasting it, it means they have it saved somewhere (like a text file), which is not as secure as their brain - so if the text file becomes useless, maybe they'll rely on their memory more.

Of course these don't actually make sense. A lot of people who copy and paste are doing so from their password manager, which is very well protected. Password managers automatically clear the clipboard as well, and as pointed out elsewhere, what are the odds that your user got a keylogger that can read the clipboard but not the key presses?

To me, things like this reveal a kind of contempt for the user's intelligence. It's basically saying, "you are too dumb to not get your password stolen, you are too dumb to follow simple security guidelines, we are just going to strap this baby harness on you to protect you from yourself". Nevermind that when your login details are stolen, it's far more likely to be because of a data breach on the server side, rather than some clipboard leak on the client side. I try to avoid such sites if at all possible, since they make me think I'm not the right audience for the site.

Luckily many password managers these days are starting to just emulate key presses instead of straight up pasting, so in the end the joke's on them.

Answer (score 9):

I can actually think of *exactly one* good reason to disallow password pasting. When initially setting your password, or changing it.

The reason is that there does exist a small chance that for whatever reason, you failed to copy your password into the clipboard when you thought you had, and so what you paste into the password field is actually just whatever nonsense was on your clipboard before that. Since the password field is masked, you'd have no way of knowing that you've just pasted

`826 W. Main St.` into the new password field, instead of

`Bubblez84-l0ve!`
or
`h*7dn$l83k&(4;p`

like you thought you had. Which will be a real problem the next time you try to log in.

Comment: So what? There is password recovery. Also you likely will also paste that password tp permanent storage before/after you set it on web site and you should either notice or just have it the same anyway.

Comment: @akostadinov if (you thought) you copied the password *from* somewhere, it's unlikely you'd put forth any special effort to also paste it *into* a clear text space near the same time. Unless you're like me and have actually experienced the situation firsthand where you take the action that should copy something, but doesn't, *and* realized that that was what had happened.

Comment: A good way to get rid of this problem is to stop masking the passwords. It adds very little security in most situations.

Comment: @pipe I'm with you. It only really helps if you're in a public space and/or somebody is likely to be looking over your shoulder at all times. Having an option to reveal the password (which actually seems to be becoming a thing as of late) is completely fine. A lot of times users won't have somebody literally watching over their shoulder. And besides, if somebody _was_ watching them, then it's not like masking helps that much. The person watching can also note what you type or will also see what you copied. They aren't as likely to remember it but...the situations aren't that likely, either.

Comment: @pipe it does make sense during screencasts or presentations. Unless, of course, the password owner shouts the password to the presenter just beforehand.

Comment: "826 W. Main St." as a password has 66 bits of entropy, "Bubblez84-l0ve!" has 76 and "h*7dn$l83k&(4;p" has 64. Other than having no clue what your password is you could do worse in terms of difficulty to guess.

Comment: @pipe One exception to this is on mobile devices. Most soft-keyboards automatically adapt their suggestions based on what you type through them, but they'll typically suppress the collection of this telemetry when interacting with masked fields.

Comment: @VLAZ They wouldn't see what they copied.  With my password manager, I can generate, copy, and paste the password, without it ever being revealed to me.  I don't know if this is a good idea, but I can.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a product manager for online security at a very large company.

I actually had a meeting today regarding the disabling of pasting passwords. 
We do allow to paste passwords at the moment but think about changing it.

There are different perspectives you can take on this approach and the pros/cons may completely vary depending on the use case you have and how your site is secured and if you use 2FA or not.

Personally i would not disable the pasting of passwords for sites that only rely on username & password for the login.

I'm thinking about disabling it in our case for several reasons

- The strength of your password does not make you more secure in our case. Yeah, i know we are telling people since ages that they should choose a reasonably secure password but in the end this won't help you/us a bit if your computer is infected by malware. Malware doesn't care if your password is "12345" or some super complicated 100 character cypher. It either steals it or takes over your session.
- We don't face the risk of brute-force or password-guessing attacks. There are ways to mitigate against that which are in place in our case.
- There are behavioral biometrics solutions where profiles are built based on keystroke dynamics etc. which allow with a high degree of certainty to identify if a user that enters the credentials is indeed the user we expect. Credentials are true or false. If somebody has your credentials he is able to authenticate. This is why i would like to know if the person who is entering the correct credentials is indeed the person that we expect to know them. Username and password have to be entered every time during the login process so those fields are pretty interesting to check if such a solution is deployed at the organisation. This is not possible if somebody copy/pastes their password.

I have not made up my mind about disabling it in our case yet. 
As always we need to keep a balance between usability and security.

Comment: In my eyes, your arguments do not hold. "The strength of your password does not make you more secure in our case." - Then, why do you have passwords at all? And when I always choose strong passwords (using e.g. a pw manager), why should I make an exception for your site?

Comment: "We don't face the risk of brute-force or password-guessing attacks." - Brute-force attacks are done with a script sending data directly to your server, not with a browser. Disabling pasting annoys your legitimate users, not hackers.

Comment: "There are behavioral biometrics solutions where profiles are built based on keystroke dynamics etc." - What would you do if a user enters correct credentials but with "wrong dynamics"? Deny access? And using complex passwords, I am very much prone to mistype and retype them a lot. I think you would never yield the same "dynamic" from me twice.

Comment: @Dubu I suspect that correct credentials with wrong dynamics would lead to an identity challenge, along the lines of: *Biometric data is inconsistent with user "Dubu". Secondary verification required. Please [answer this security question/type the code we just texted to you/check your registered email address for a verification link].*

Comment: Point 1 - it's in favour of pasting. If it doesn't matter whether the user is protected, then disabling it _still_ doesn't matter but tends to annoy users. Net gain - nil for security, point for usability. Point 2 - a point against whoever thinks brute forcing is done through the web page. Net gain: -1 for security. Point 3. - the biometrics are shit. It's inconsistent. Typing with one hand, the wrong hand (on mobile), different keyboard, different place can affect it and issue a challenge. Lots of false positives. Even if a user's typing is consistent, it would probably not be that unique.

Comment: @DanHenderson FYI, if I even see "Biometric data is inconsistent with user "Dronz". Secondary verification required." I am going to consider ending my relationship with whatever company put that in place, and will probably publicly complain about it, mentioning the company name in angry ways, regularly for years (decades?) to come. On the other hand, if it sent _me_ an email about it, as an FYI, I might not mind.

Comment: Upvoted just because it's a counter argument and therefore much more varied than many of the answers above it.

Comment: Another form of brute force attack, against which I highly suspect your mitigation techniques will do nothing, is where the database of encrypted passwords is stolen, and then the attackers perform the attack against the stolen copy of the database on their own hardware, without the risk of triggering any lockouts, rate limiting, etc. that are implemented in your environment.

Comment: Maybe you could look at [NIST's thoughts on the subject](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html): _"Verifiers SHOULD permit claimants to use “paste” functionality when entering a memorized secret."_

Answer (score 1):

Many of the answers point out this is bad practice because it can break password managers. While the use of password managers should be encouraged storing passwords in the clipboard should be strongly discouraged. The clipboard is not some special secure locker for information and by design makes it contents easy to access and offers no encryption.

Here is just one scenario of how this could be exploited:

- User copies password in plain text.
- User visits another website with a Flash application while just surfing the web. Or the website was sent to the victim intentionally by the attacker.
- Flash allows access to the clipboard as an API. So the clipboard contents are easily accessed and can sent to the attacker.

There have even been cases where someone bought a bunch of rich media ads on a bunch of well know websites. While they looked like a seemingly harmless flash ad it was actually stealing the visitors clipboard data in hopes of getting useful information.

So in closing, **if you have something you want to keep safe and secure don't store it in the clipboard**.

Comment: ...or just copy something else into the clipboard right afterwards.

Comment: Or don’t use Flash on your login page.

Comment: A password manager usually clears the clipboard after a few seconds. Mine also uses a combination of typing and selective copy/pasting, as such my password is never completely readable in my clipboard or typing history (e.g. keylogger's log file)

Comment: @DanHanderson you can see clipboard history using some programs

Comment: @ardaozkal The clipboard on Windows does not have a history but you're right that a program could make its own history.

Comment: @JDługosz It's not a matter of using Flash on your login page. It's a matter of your end user having Flash installed and going to a site with a malicious Flash application embedded.

Comment: @DanHenderson The OP stated their cell phone company does this. Cell phones are widely used by not so technical or cautious people. So the cell provider is likely assuming the customer is doing nothing to protect themselves.

Comment: @baconface Sorry, what are you saying that the OP stated their cell company does? I don't see any mention that the company "cop[ies] something else into the clipboard right afterwards"...

Comment: @ardaozkal such a program has to already be running before you copy the things to the clipboard. Under normal circumstances, the Windows clipboard unrecoverably discards its previous contents when something new is copied.

Comment: @DanHenderson Second paragraph. It mentions they block the ability for their users to paste from the clipboard.

Comment: @baconface that's a totally different thing from what I said, though. Here, let me clarify. From your answer: "If you have something you want to keep safe and secure don't store it in the clipboard." Me: "Or, just copy something else into the clipboard right after [you're done using the clipboard for that one thing]." See? What I said was not anything that OP stated their cell company does.

Comment: Microsoft Office [keeps a history of previous contents of the Clipboard](http://i.stack.imgur.com/05vu8.png), including things copied by non-Microsoft programs. It does provide [a capability to delete items from the history](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1zVfL.png), and so we might hope that password managers use that capability, but simply copying new information onto the Clipboard does not erase the history.

Comment: @DanHenderson I was pointing out what his cell company is doing is not a "what I can do to protect myself" situation. It is a "what I can do to protect my users" situation. While I do point out it isn't safe for you to put secrets in the clipboard I was also pointing how/why the company is addressing it.

Comment: It's far more likely that a password breach or brute force attack will happen than any of these problems.

Comment: @baconface do you have a reference for flash having access to the user's clipboard with no interaction from the user? according to this http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/fplayer10_uia_requirements.html it requires user interaction to get the system clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have given more in-depth explanations, but in short remember that the biggest security risk with regards to passwords still comes from attacks targeted at the servers, not at a client. In other words, having your password on the clipboard doesn't really put it at much risk because if the password were to be cracked it would more likely be cracked from a password database stolen from the server or even bruteforced than stolen from your clipboard.

Hence why it is significant that, as other answers have pointed out, preventing a user from pasting their password discourages them from having a complex password, making their password easier to bruteforce and therefore less secure.

Answer (score -3):

I think it depends on the services which are secured by the login form. It is important to consider that a password manager can restrict the login to the device where the password manager is installed, which is not always what the service provider agrees with. For example, if the service was a bank which wants to give their users the opportunity to lock cards in case of loss or thievery, it may want to preserve this privilege in cases where the device running the password manager was also lost or stolen.

Comment: How could a password manager stop you logging in on another device? And your last sentence is somewhat unclear.

Comment: As @AakashM has pointed out, I see no reason why using a password manager would prevent me from login in from a different device. I either install the pw manager on that device as well, memorize the password or type it over.

Comment: Are you trying to say that a bank might not want users to use password managers because then they would be unable to log on to cancel their cards if the computer was taken in the same theft? If so, you should remove the last "not" and find a clear phrase than "restrict the login to the device".

Comment: Password managers may be used to facilitate the usage of passwords that are hard to memorize. So, making it easy to use them might at least reduce the chance of users being able to login without the password manager.

Comment: so @distacle you're suggesting some banks might want to _discourage_ their users from using password managers, or even using hard passwords, because... if their bank card AND computer were stolen, they might not be able to log in (on somebody else's device) to report the theft.   I just wanted to be sure I understood your suggestion.